# Magento get adminhtml url to view single shipment on order

Tags: magento

I can generate adminhtml "view order" url for orders from magento increment_id like this:

```
<?php
$order_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100001234')->getId();
?>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order_id)) ?>">
    Click here to view order
</a>
```

I want to achieve the same for shipment. I have increment_id of shipments I generate programatically.

Is there a way to generate an adminhtml "view shipment" url by shipment increment id (like I did above for view order)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
<?php
  $shipment_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')
    ->loadByIncrementId($shipmentIncrementId)
    ->getId();

  $shipment_url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')
    ->getUrl(
      'adminhtml/sales_order_shipment/view',
      array('shipment_id' => $shipment_id));
?>
<a href="<?php echo $shipment_url ?>">
  Click here to view shipment
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hi you can use below code
 $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($shipmentIncrementId);

and can get more information from magento documnet
http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment.html( search for http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment.html)

and http://www.magentodocs.org/1.7.0.2/db/dec/app_2code_2core_2_mage_2_sales_2_model_2_order_2_shipment_2api_8php_source.php()( search for  public function info($shipmentIncrementId))
```